# How I can select which Microphones I use on Android?

Tags: android, input, microphone

I have an app who are connected with webrtc. I have to had a selected part, where I can select which mic I use.

I already can display the list of mic connected (intern, Bluetooth, ...), I can return some value when I select one of this list. Those values can be name, id type ... 
For do this, i use `getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_INPUTS)`

So How I can select one of these devices?

Thanks for any help. A link to an example or tutorial can be good!

Answer (score 0):

[getDevices](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#getDevices(int)) (AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_INPUTS) returns a list of [AudioDeviceInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioDeviceInfo) instances. Select the one that you need from the list, and pass that instance to an AudioRecord object via a call to [setPreferredDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord#setPreferredDevice(android.media.AudioDeviceInfo))